# Watch and rerun Jest JS tests

Tags: npm, jestjs

The [Jest](http://facebook.github.io/jest/) documentation suggests using `npm test` to execute tests.

Is there a way of watching your source and tests to rerun Jest tests automatically when relevant files have been changed?

Answer (score 198, accepted):

Thanks to Erin Stanfill for pointing out, Jest already has support for [automatically re-running](https://facebook.github.io/jest/#use-the-watch-option-to-automatically-re-run-tests). The better configuration for `package.json` would be

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  }
}
```

To turn on the watch mode, just use

```sh
$ npm run test -- --watch
```

Or

```sh
$ yarn run test --watch
```

Comment: An important thing to point out is that nodemon will interrupt the tests and start again if a change happens while the tests are running. `grunt watch` will not, it will continue the current test-run ignoring changes that occur while the tests are running.

Comment: It might be a better edit to just remove the first answer? The edit works great for me, and it was, at a glance, confusing to read both together.

Comment: I have a file named string.utility.spec.js, and this will be picked up an run when I execute "npm run test", but not when I run "npm run test -- --watch". Renaming the file to "string.spec.js" will cause it to be picked up and run. Weird.

Comment: @TigerBear You can overwrite this behavior, see https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/configuration.html#testmatch-array-string

Comment: why do we need -- before --watch?

Comment: @VishalAnand  npm will pass all the arguments after the -- directly to the script. [link](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script).

Comment: watch can also be added to "scripts": { "test": "jest --watch" }, and then you can just use npm run test

Comment: You can even `yarn test --watch`!

Answer (score 43):

If you have `npm test` configured, you can just run `npm test -- --watch`.

Answer (score 12):

As a complement suggestion you can add "--watchAll"
into your package.json file like this:

```
"scripts": {       
  "test": "jest --watchAll"
},
```

Each time you run npm test, the watch mode will be enable by default.

For more info [npm CLI docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/commands/npm-test)

Answer (score 3):

Start you tests in watch mode.

```
jest --watch fileName.test.js
```

As per documentation

Run tests that match this spec name (match against the name in `describe` or `test`, basically).

```
jest -t name-of-spec
// or in watch mode
jest --watch -t="TestName"
```

Answer (score 1):

1. install a couple of Grunt packages:

   ```
   npm install grunt-contrib-watch grunt-exec --save-dev
   ```
2. make a `Gruntfile.js` with the following:

   ```
   module.exports = function(grunt) {
       grunt.initConfig({
           exec: {
               jest: 'node node_modules/jest-cli/bin/jest'
           },
           watch: {
               files: ['**/*.js'],
               tasks: ['exec:jest']
           }
       });
       grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
       grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-exec');
   }
   ```
3. then simply run:

   ```
   grunt watch
   ```

Answer (score 1):

[This example](https://github.com/iaretiga/gulp-jest-watcher) shows how to use gulp to run your Jest tests using `jest-cli`, as well as a `tdd` gulp task to watch files and rerun Jest tests when a file changes:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var jest = require('jest-cli');

var jestConfig = {
    rootDir: 'source'
};

gulp.task('test', function(done) {
    jest.runCLI({ config : jestConfig }, ".", function() {
        done();
    });
});

gulp.task('tdd', function(done) {
    gulp.watch([ jestConfig.rootDir + "/**/*.js" ], [ 'test' ]);
});

gulp.task('default', function() {
    // place code for your default task here
});
```

Comment: For some reason despite I use the default `__tests__` folder it does not work with this `jestConfig`. After reading the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/api.html#config-rootdir-string) and playing a bit this works for me: 
`var jestConfig = {  rootDir: "__tests__" }`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run **a single file** in watch mode:

```
yarn run test --watch FileName.test.jsx
```

Comment: `npm run test -- --watch FileName.test.jsx`

Answer (score 0):

I personally use the npm package [jest-watch-typeahead](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-watch-typeahead).

You need to do 3 steps:

1. Install npm packege:

> npm install --save-dev jest jest-watch-typeahead

2. Add to jest.config.js next code:

> ```
> module.exports = {
>   watchPlugins: [
>     'jest-watch-typeahead/filename',
>     'jest-watch-typeahead/testname',
>   ],
> };
> ```

3. Run Jest in watch mode

> yarn jest --watch

Answer (score 0):

###### you can add the following script to watch all your js files for changes

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
    "watch": "jest --watch .js"
  }
}
```

- ###### you can run `npm test` to run your tests ones and you can run `npm run watch` to run your tests every time you make changes to your test files and save them